# AspNet.WebApi.Versioning changes model binding behavior for IEnumerable parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, owin

I recently introduced the package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning` ([github](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning)) in my project in order to version my API.

It works like a charm, but unfortunately, it has a weird side effect. It changes the default parameter value for a `IEnumerable<T>` uri parameter from `null` to an empty `List<T>`. I isolated it, using the basic example from the package repository.

Calling http://localhost:xxx/api/v1/helloworld returns

`ids is null: True` if versioning is **not** enabled (previous behavior)

`ids is null: False` if versioning is enabled

I'm afraid, that it changes other behaviors as well. How can I keep the version feature, but use the default model binding?

**Controller**

```
// breaks
[Microsoft.Web.Http.ApiVersion("1.0")]
[RoutePrefix( "api/v{version:apiVersion}/helloworld" )]

// working
//[RoutePrefix("api/v1/helloworld")]
public class HelloWorldController : ApiController
{
    [Route]
    public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] IEnumerable<Guid> ids)
    {
        return Ok($"ids is null: {ids == null}");
    }
}
```

**Setup**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration( IAppBuilder builder )
    {
        var configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
        var httpServer = new HttpServer( configuration );


        // breaks:
        configuration.AddApiVersioning();
        var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver() { ConstraintMap = { ["apiVersion"] = typeof(ApiVersionRouteConstraint) } };
        configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);

        // defaut (works)
        //configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        builder.UseWebApi( httpServer );
    }
}
```

**Reproduce**

```
git clone https://github.com/smstuebe/webapi-versioning-parameter-binding.git
git checkout working
# if you want to break it
git checkout broken
```